# How to change states in US voting registration

Tags: united-states, voting, voter-registration

If I am changing the state I am registered to vote in, do I need to somehow “unregister” in my old state?

I confirmed that my registration is valid in my old state. My new state’s registration form makes me certify that I’m not claiming the right to vote anywhere else. My new state isn’t actually the state on my ID (driver’s license) but that’s not a problem (new state is NY and they don’t mind).

I can register in the new state no problem, I’m just not sure what to do about the previous registration, if anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I am changing the state I am registered to vote in, do I need to somehow “unregister” in my old state?

No.  All you need to do is register in the new state.  The old state is supposed to figure it out, possibly by being notified by the new state.

This is also true if you switch counties within a state, as it is actually the counties that track the registration in most (if not all) states.  So technically speaking, you are changing jurisdiction when you move from one county to another in such a state.

You may truthfully certify that you are not claiming the right to vote in your old state so long as you don't plan to do so.  Of course, if New York then notifies your old state, they could reasonably take you off their voter rolls.  That could potentially cause problems if you moved back.

Comment: Under NVRA he *can* notify the old jurisdiction, but it's not a requirement.